# How to initialize vector of a vector with custom values?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector < vector <int> > g;
g.resize(n + 1);
```

I want to initialize n + 1 value all with -1. I know how to do it for a single vector but how it happens in this one.

Comment: Not quite sure about the version but it is the recent one. Yes, I want all values in 2 dimensions to be -1.

Comment: Don't nest vectors like this! It's poison for your CPU cache, and explodes the number of allocations required. Have a nice `vector<int>` instead... you can overlay 2D indexing on top of that

Comment: You say you want a 2D vector, but what size(s) do you want the inner `vector`s to have?  The outer vector will be `n+1` number of vectors, the inner vectors will be X number of ints, what do you want X to be?

Comment: Usually, instead of a 2D vector I would use a vector for size `m * n` and index using `i + j * n`

Comment: it is n + 1 as well. It will create an adjacent matrix.

Comment: @Rarblack If the 2D table is rectangular it is far better to implement a single `std::vector` with a length of `width * height` instead. You can index a cell at `x, y` with `g[x+y*width]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can nest initializations:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> g(n, std::vector<int>(m, -1));
```

This will declare `g` as a vector with `n` elements, where each element is a vector with `m` elements, where each element in those sub-vectors is -1.

Comment: basically, I was remembering someone doing it with resize but couldn't recall it. Will use that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Both the constructor and `resize()` method of `std::vector` let you specify the value to be applied to new elements that are created when expanding the `vector`'s size, eg:

```cpp
vector<vector<int> > g;
g.resize(n + 1, std::vector<int>(n + 1, -1));
```

Or:

```cpp
vector<vector<int> > g(n + 1, std::vector<int>(n + 1, -1));
```

Note that in either case, you are creating a temporary `vector<int>` of `n+1` elements and then making `n+1` *copies* of that temporary in the outer `vector`. To avoid those copies, you can do something like this instead:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int> > g(n+1);
for(size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); ++i) {
    g[i].resize(m, -1);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> g(n+1);
for(auto &v : g) {
    v.resize(m, -1);
}
```

---

That being said, try not to use nested `vector`s, if you can help it.  It would be more efficient on memory usage and CPU operations to allocate a single 1-dimensional `vector` instead, and then just use 2-dimensional indexing with it, eg:

```cpp
const int size = n+1;
std::vector<int> g(size*size, -1);
...
int x = ...;
int y = ...;
g[(x*size)+y] = ...;
... = g[(x*size)+y];
```